# Unable to upload JSON file greater than 5kb in size via PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to upload a file to a server in JSON format using Curl. This is coming from a PHP script, which works for JSON files less than 5kb.  code below

```
$ch = curl_init( $url );
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $uploadJson );
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
                    $result = curl_exec($ch);
                    $status= curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                    print $status.PHP_EOL;
                    if($status=="500")
                    {
                        $errorMsg="The error is ".curl_error($ch);
                        print $errorMsg.PHP_EOL;
                    }
                    curl_close($ch);
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this, fairly new to PHP  and Curl. Thank you for any advice you can offer,
James

Comment: you have to configure your php variable on server

Comment: Could you please explain that?

Comment: what type of server u use? "Apache" or the server is on the remote?

Comment: it sounds like the timeOut is fired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just changed the type to application/octet-stream and that solved the problem.